# Django Session Form (save form temporarily)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-sessions

I have created a page for review form. All users can fill out the form, but only logged in users can submit the form. If users is not logged in, they will be redirected to the login page. After they login, they will be redirected to the profile page.

**So the flow will be like this  :**
User fills out the form > click the submit > redirected to login page > user login and redirected to profile page (at the same time, the form they have filled in is automatically saved)

**I want the form they have filled in automatically saved after they login. How to do that?**

**My idea is** to create a session that saves the form temporarily, then save to database after they login. But I'm confused how to write the code

Can anyone explain a bit what a django session is like? and how to write code to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try something like,

1 User fills out the form and hits submit

2 in the POST view where you handle the form, use the "**is_authenticated**" function and, 
    a)if the user is authenticated you handle the form as usual...
    b)else set the contents of the form into a session variable in the views and redirect to the login page like,

request.session['review_body'] = request.post.get(the_form_body_field)

3 as per what you've said, after login it goes to profile page and form is submitted...
    a)so in views where you serve the profile page, check if the session variable containing form data's exist and has values
    b)if yes, directly save the contents from your views and clear the session data
```

Comment: For number 3, I'm using django-allauth for authentication. So I have two option, override the login view from django-allauth, and create django signals. Which one is better?

Comment: Hello, I want to ask .. what if the form contains image fields? Because we can't save images in django session

Comment: Hi penk! Yes, it is a bad idea to store image data in session. The best thing you can do is save the form as usual in a db. Add a boolean field (example "form_pending") and set it to false if an un-authorized users fills the form.. Then after successful login check if the logged in user has a "form_pending" true field in DB and if so,  set it to False and redirect to the profile page